# BeautifulSoup4 Converting HTML entities (non-breaking space?) BEFORE the search (Python 3.X)

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm looking to use BeautifulSoup4 and either urllib or requests to scrape some documents, but some of them have *&nbsp* in them instead of normal spaces. In some of the documents, there are lines like the following:

```
"Pursuant to&nbspthe requirements&nbspof Section&nbsp13..."
```

but they can be placed anywhere, so they need to be replaced by spaces, ex:

```
"Pursuant to the requirements of Section 13...."
```

I need to replace them before I do the soup.find(), so something like this:

```
#code to get request from server goes here

soup=BeautifulSoup(requestedPage)
#remove nbsp
sectionRequired=soup.find(text=re.compile("Pursuant to the requirements of Section 13"))
```

How am I able to replace the &nbsp spaces with normal spaces in a webpage BEFORE I use the bs4 find function, so I can do a string match in the soup.find()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `html.parser.unescape()`:

```
import html.parser as hp
import re 

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(hp.unescape(data), "lxml")

p = soup.find(text=re.compile("Pursuant to the requirements of Section 13"))
print(p)
```

Why you text fails is there is a newline also, the following regex works:

```
p = soup.find(text=re.compile("Pursuant\s+to\s+the\s+requirements\s+of\s+Section\s+13"))
```

Running it on:

```
In [15]: url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000110465907013496/a07-1583_110k.htm"

In [16]: response = requests.get(url, headers={
   ....:     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"
   ....: })

In [17]: data = response.text

In [18]: soup = BeautifulSoup(hp.unescape(data), "lxml")

In [19]: p = soup.find(text=re.compile("Pursuant\s+to\s+the\s+requirements\s+of\s+Section\s+13"))

In [20]: print(p)
Pursuant to the
requirements of Section 13 or 15(d) of the Securities Exchange Act of
1934, Abbott Laboratories has duly caused this report to be signed on its
behalf by the undersigned, thereunto duly authorized.
```

You see after `Pursuant to the` there is a newline so your text could not match. Using `\s+` will work for any whitespace. The unescaping is also not actually needed, the text match will work fine.

To get the second table after:

```
table = p.find_next("table").find_next("table")
```

Which gives you:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="font-size:10.0pt;margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><!-- SET mrlNoTableShading -->/s/ MILES D.
  WHITE</p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="top" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ ROXANNE S.
  AUSTIN</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="font-size:10.0pt;margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><!-- SET mrlHTMLTableFull --><!-- SET mrlNoTableShading -->Miles D. White<br/>
  Chairman of the Board, Chief Executive<br/>
  Officer and Director of Abbott Laboratories<br/>
  (principal executive officer)</p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="top" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Roxanne S. Austin<br/>
  Director of Abbott Laboratories</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="margin:24.0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ RICHARD A. GONZALEZ</font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:24.0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="top" width="288">
<p style="margin:24.0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ WILLIAM M. DALEY</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Richard A. Gonzalez<br/>
  President and Chief Operating Officer<br/>
  and Director of Abbott Laboratories</font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="top" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">William M. Daley<br/>
  Director of Abbott Laboratories</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="margin:24.0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ THOMAS C. FREYMAN</font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="bottom" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ W.
  JAMES FARRELL</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Thomas C. Freyman<br/>
  Executive Vice President, Finance<br/>
  and Chief Financial Officer<br/>
  (principal financial officer)</font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="top" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">W. James Farrell<br/>
  Director of Abbott Laboratories</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="margin:24.0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ GREG W. LINDER</font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="bottom" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">/s/ H.
  LAURANCE FULLER</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="page-break-inside:avoid;">
<td style="border:none;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:210.0pt;" valign="top" width="280">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">Greg W. Linder<br/>
  Vice President and Controller<br/>
  (principal accounting officer)</font></p>
</td>
<td style="padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:30.0pt;" valign="top" width="40">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:1.0pt;"> </font></p>
</td>
<td style="border:none;padding:0pt .7pt 0pt 0pt;width:215.7pt;" valign="top" width="288">
<p style="margin:0pt 0pt .0001pt;"><font face="Times New Roman" size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;">H. Laurance Fuller<br/>
  Director of Abbott Laboratories</font></p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've implemented your fix, but when I do the next step, I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. This means that the find didn't work, so there's still something wrong. If you want to use the link that I'm using, here's the link: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/000110465907013496/a07-1583_110k.htm

Comment: Right, so the regex will deal with the newlines and the unescape deals with the unicode characters?

Comment: @Retroflux, you don't really need the unescape, it should work fine without

Comment: Isn't `soup = BeautifulSoup(hp.unescape(data), "lxml")` dangerous since `data` may contain escaped text with special html symbols in it?